# How to turn String Value into Number - Google Tag Manager

Tags: string, facebook, type-conversion, google-tag-manager

Im setting up my **Google Tag Manager** and I want to grab the **purchase value from my Data Layer**. This works fine, but Facebook doesn't recognize this value as its a "String" and not a number.

Therefore **my question is**: How can I convert this String (Return Type) to a Number (Return Type) in order for Facebook to pick it up? If that helps, its a currency.

Comment: Can you share your code and explain the specific area you need help. With this its hard to understand what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1):

### Create JavaScript Variable named "String2Number Convertor"

```
function(){
  return function(s){
    return +s;
  }
}
```

### Create another JavaScript Variable named "Facebook Purchase Value"

```
function(){
  return {{String2Number Convertor}}({{DataLayer Conversion Value}})
}
```

I assume you have your purchase value in data layer variable I called in this example as **DataLayer Conversion Value**

With this approach you can convert any other variables into number.